# SOQL - Query for Last Name of Contacts

Tags: soql, contact, filters, search

I am trying to query for Contacts by Last Name. I understand the error I am receiving, but I am unsure of the cause.

I think one of the following might be the potential root causes:

- Name is of the data type "Name".
- Platform encryption is on.

What are my options? As a workaround, currently I am using SOSL to search in Name Fields, then parse through that return of contacts to pull out the contacts where the LastName of that contact is == the search string, but this is taking too long to parse through all of the returns I get for common names because it is searching in ALL Name fields.

If this is not a bug or an oversight, I'm thinking of using a formula text field to get the LastName so I am able to SOQL directly for that field.

**The following query returns the following error:**

```
SELECT Id, LastName from Contact where LastName = 'Smith'
```

> field 'LastName' can not be filtered in a query call

**The following query does not return an error:**

```
SELECT Id, LastName from Contact
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Shield Platform Encryption turned on in your org and have that field encrypted you will get an error message; not sure if it's exactly that one though. See the SOQL/SOSL section of [General Shield Platform Encryption Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_considerations_general.htm&type=5).

You would get that message for a custom long text area field.

**PS**

So it sounds like it is the encryption. First thing to read is this [ISVPlatformEncryption](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/ISVPlatformEncryption#Key_limitations_and_their_workarounds) document that includes sections like "Key limitations and their workarounds". The code example they supply for a similar situation to yours is this combination of dynamic SOQL and using a SOSL find:

```
List<Contact> conts;
If (Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.MailingCity.isFilterable() ){
      //Filterable, so use SOQL
      conts = Database.query('Select ID, Name, MailingCity from Contact WHERE MailingCity = \'PARIS\'');

} else {
      //Not filterable, so use SOSL
      List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND 'PARIS' IN ALL Fields RETURNING Contact (Id, Name, MailingCity)];
      conts = searchList.get(0);
}
```

Comment: "Encrypted fields that use the probabilistic encryption scheme can’t be used with the following SOQL and SOSL clauses and functions:
--WHERE clause"

Yep. So now we have a cause... are there any other solutions to make this search more efficient?

Comment: Currently taking a look into deterministic encryption... a setting in Salesforce that allows queries on specific fields set on the on platform encryption policy page. Will post results...

Comment: @S.B. See my PS. Not pretty but we've had to do it and it works. That was a couple of years ago though so there may be other options now.